# JavaFX indeterminate progress dialog overlay

Tags: java, javafx

I have a WebView.

When loading stuff that takes a long time, I want the WebView to be overlaid with a loading dialog that looks like the progress dialog in phones - the one with the circular spinning thing, and darken the screen area that is not covered by the dialog.

Additionally, I want to make it impossible for the user to click on anything on the WebView until it is ready.

How do I achieve this effect in Java 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you need the loading call this

```
private void inUrFace(){
Dialog<Void> dialog = new Dialog<>();
dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
dialog.initOwner(stage);//stage here is the stage of your webview
dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
Label loader = new Label("LOADING");
loader.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.DOWN);
loader.setGraphic(new ProgressIndicator());
dialog.getDialogPane().setGraphic(loader);
DropShadow ds = new DropShadow();
ds.setOffsetX(1.3); ds.setOffsetY(1.3); ds.setColor(Color.DARKGRAY);
dialog.getDialogPane().setEffect(ds);
dialog.showAndWait();}
```

double check the code. should give you something of that sort.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the modal thing does not work as intended, because I am still able to click buttons and whatever.

Comment: are you sure you have the owner stage set? you can go for `scene.getWindow()`  or something like `WebView.getScene().getWindow()` it should work, it will not work only if owner is null @user3635998

Comment: Maybe this is why... I am using Swing and FX combined. The Window Object is not null, the Dark Gray thing does not show to cover the WebView, and when the user moves the window, the dialog does not move with it (I am guessing that it should be set when I detect the swing JFrame moving).

Comment: This work for me, but I'm not able to close the dialog. I've tried dialog.close() and dialog.hide() but neither ot them works. Any ideas?

Comment: @jmartinalonso its because of the dialog closing rules Sir, please read the [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) hope it helps

Comment: to close dialog use: `dialog.setResult(ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE); dialog.close();` even if you don't have any buttons in the dialog.